# Go UDP message-receiving freezes

Tags: go, udp

I am trying to write a program that communicates over UDP using Go.

It's supposed to have a master/slave architecture, and therefore I want the master to send an "alive"-signal ten times a second. Since I also want the master to listen for messages from the slaves, I start a goroutine with the receive function.

In testing I only use one computer, so that the only thing it receives is it's own alive-signal. Yet, after receiving about 20 messages the program freezes.

I've tried running the program only sending messages, and it doesn't freeze. Here is the receive function:

```
func receive(conn *net.UDPConn){
  //Receive message from network
  received := make([]byte,1024)
  for ; true ; {
    _, _, _ = conn.ReadFromUDP(received)
    println("Motatt: ", string(received))
    go receiveMessage(string(received))
  }
}
```

The function receiveMessage() is simply a function that reads the message it has received.

What I am wondering is if there is a setting or something in GO that causes the freeze? As far as I understand it cannot be a deadline error since there are messages to receive.

Comment: Can you check the error send back by ReadFromUDP, in case it gives you a clue?

Comment: are you sure there's data to read?  is the publisher on the same host?  go, by default, disables loopback for mcast.  You have to do some syscalls to see packets send from your own address.

Comment: There are no errors coming from ReadFromUDP. But I see now that I may have been a little quick in blaming UDP for the error. In the 6th line in the code where I print the message (motatt means received) it prints "Motatt", and freezes before it prints the message. So the error may be in the casting and not in the UDP.

Comment: probably you should grab the size instead of ignoring and maybe print string(received[:size]), but a bunch of nulls wouldnt cause it to freeze... random binary data in the packet may cause your terminal to go weird... maybe run your app and pipe to hexdump or something

Comment: It might be the terminal going weird, but it do seem to have something to do with the size of the receive buffer. When I decrease the size from 1024 to 100 it runs for a longer time, but freezes eventually. Thanks for your help! I think I can fix this with some trial and error.

Comment: Did you try not calling `go receiveMessage` and just printing?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that as well. It works for a little while, then stops working. It seems the problem was a bit bigger than I imagined, so I haven't found a solution yet. Tried using json, but the problem is still the same.